# How to prevent rollback in trigger after an adderror is thrown

Tags: apex

I have an After event trigger on object A where in I have a condition checked in object A with addError and an update in object B.

During bulk dataload, when the condition in object A fails the adderror is thrown  and the DML in object B is rolled back.

I have tried future calls as well. It did not work.

Can anyone help!

Thanks
NB

Comment: Please paste your trigger code so that it helps other in helping you

Comment: In Short, in after event trigger, during bulk operation, if there is AddError() , then DML operation to other objects gets rolledback

Comment: @SFDCLearner is that code working for single operation?

Comment: @SFDCLearner http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9502/can-we-have-a-dml-not-roll-back-when-i-use-an-adderror-method

Comment: Yes it is working fine for single operation

Answer (score 1):

We cannot prevent rollback when we use addError() on all rows in Apex.

However what we can do is perform partial processing using Database.insert(List objList, allORNone) or Database.Update((List objList, allORNone).

**From the [Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling):**

> The thing about partial processing is that even if individual records
>   in the update cause exceptions, an exception won't be thrown. To deal
>   with individual exceptions in this manner, we can do something like
>   this:
>
> ```
> Database.SaveResult[] lsr = Database.update(accounts, false); 
>
> for(Database.SaveResult sr&nbsp;: lsr){ 
>     if (!sr.isSuccess()) { 
>         myMethodToaddToErrorObjectList(sr);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Here we try to update a list of Accounts. The Database.update won't
>   throw an exception, because we're allowing for partial processing. We
>   then loop through the save result looking for errors. We can pass the
>   save result to a method that will do some processing of the error
>   records. And because we're doing partial processing, we won't stop the
>   post-commit processing like the sending of emails.
>
> **One thing to realize about the partial processing method--automatic
>   rollback of DMLs is disabled when you use it.** If you switch from all
>   or nothing to partial processing, you may need to change your code to
>   handle your own rollback using [Apex transaction control](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm)

Comment: How would you do that using the data loader, which is the one performing the DML?