# How long before an org shows up under Subscriber Organizations in the LMA?

Tags: appexchange, lma, grant-login-access

I have a customer who installed our app and granted us login access, but I can't log in because they don't show up under "Subscriber Organizations" in the License Management Application. Is this something that just takes a while for SFDC to update? It's been about an hour so far.

The alternative is that my customer is very confused about what they are doing.

Comment: In case, if your package is in Beta and not security reviewed by SFDC then it will not show up. Please refer to this question answers for more info - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12313/how-to-check-debug-logs-for-installed-app

Comment: No, I have a long list of customers available, including this customer running on their sandbox but now I need to get in to their production org.

Comment: Most likely cause is that yes sometimes it takes a while (just like package upload propagation does sometimes - I vaguely recall seeing this with subscriber orgs but can't confirm for sure), followed closely by your customer is confused :) Let us know the resolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The listing did eventually show up - about three hours after the customer has installed the application. So yes, it does take some time for SFDC to propagate the update.