# Can global members be added/removed from Beta packages freely?

Tags: managed-package, beta-managed-package, global-variables, global-methods

Global things can't be un-global-ed once they hit production.

However, I need to debug something in a sandbox and want to generate a temporary beta build with some methods made global. Can I switch those methods back to public in the next beta build or am I stuck with that for life?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can switch a never-production-uploaded-global back to its previous access level. You'll only be committed to it if you upload it as a production version. You can also enable "managed package debugging," which allows you to get the same debug logs you'd get as if the code were not in a managed package. This feature only works when using the Subscriber Login feature, so it helps prevents IP and data leaks. [This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47145#47158) goes in to more detail on how that works, with lots of links.