# Where can I view untruncated Duplicate Error Logs

Tags: debugging, duplicate-management

Duplicate Error Logs as rendered through *Data.com Administration > Duplicate Management > Duplicate Error Logs* are truncated around 250 characters. Is there anywhere else to view these completely? I have Apex triggers on Duplicate Record Item, but since they're executed as the Automated Process user, debug output isn't logged to standard error logs, and writing to a custom debug object fails since all actions are rolled back when there's an error.

Answer (score 0):

*This workaround doesn't explicitly answer my question and may only be applicable to a dev environment in which you don't care to throw an exception, but it solves the immediate problem of not being able to see the error message in its entirety.*

I just did away with throwing an exception and then wrote to my custom error log.

(In my case, I did not want to rollback anything, but if I did, I'd make use of System.savePoint and Database.rollback. I gleaned inspiration for this workaround from [Can I prevent an insert to be rolled back even if my class (later) runs into an exception?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10624/can-i-prevent-an-insert-to-be-rolled-back-even-if-my-class-later-runs-into-an/))

**Before**

> ```
>   try {
>       <my DML statement>
>   }
>   catch (DmlException e) {
>       myCustomErrorService.createErrorRecord(e.getMessage());
>       throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
>   }
> ```

**After**

> ```
>  String errorMessage;
>  try {
>       <my DML statement>
>  catch (DmlException e) {
>       errorMessage = (e.getMessage());
>  }
>  finally {
>       myCustomErrorService.createErrorRecord(errorMessage);
>  }
> ```

Comment: More context (specific error irrelevant here but this illustrates the problem):
Before, in Duplicate Error Log:
`Merge failed. First exception on row 0 with id ...; first error: INVALI_`

Now able to log to my custom error object, I can see the full error and proceed in debugging.
`_Merge failed. First exception on row 0 with id...; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, Unable to create/update fields: CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.: [CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate_`